# Load local html file into Pyside QwebView

Tags: python, pyside, qwebview

i want to load a local HTML file (with relative css and js files)  into my QwebView Pyside Widget but it doesnt show anything.
here is my code:

```
class SplashWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    WINDOW_WIDTH= 800
    WINDOW_HEIGHT=600

    WINDOW_TITLE="Splash"
    WINDOW_FOOTER_MESSAGE="Some Text here for [X] Project 2016"
    WINDOW_PARENT=None
    view=None

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SplashWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.WINDOW_PARENT=parent
        self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.addWidgets()

        self.view = QWebView(self)
        self.view.setMinimumSize(self.WINDOW_WIDTH,self.WINDOW_HEIGHT-100)
        self.view.setMaximumSize(self.WINDOW_WIDTH,self.WINDOW_HEIGHT-100)
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        self.view.load(QUrl("file://"+cwd+"\\resource\\Splash.html"))
        self.view.show()

        button = MyWidgets.createPushButton("btn",self,100,100,self.complete_name)
        button.move(100,100)
```

how can i fix this?

my html file is in resource folder in root dir of my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved just replace:

```
self.view.load(QUrl("file://"+cwd+"\\resource\\Splash.html"))
```

to:

```
self.view.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(cwd+"\\resource\\Splash.html"))
```

Comment: Using `os.getcwd()` is broken: there is no guarantee that it will be the same as the root directory of your project. Use `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` to get the directory of the current module.